# Can I run an SVN server with repository on mapped drive?

Tags: svn

SVN questions seem OK here. Apologies if not.

I run an SVN server on my Windows desktop machine for a tiny group, mostly myself with a couple of checkers-out. My repository is on a network share set up as a mapped drive on that box. I know there are problems using file:// access to the repo on a share, but I use only svn:// to access it. My clients are Tortoise SVN on the same machine as the server and a couple of team members, and Cornerstone on my development Mac.

Am I asking for trouble? Should I move the repo to my desktop and have a backup job copy it to the file server overnight instead? I've had it up for a year without problems but I finally read the docs yesterday and scared myself.

Justification is this: our internal IT only backs up file servers, not desktops. Our "official" SC system is MS Visual SourceSafe, which is not available to my skunk works team (and stinks besides.) Setting up an svn server in our racks will ruffle a lot of feathers that I need to stay smooth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with using SVN hosted on a file server comes from the use of the file:// protocol access as it isn't very robust to multiple users committing at the same time.  However if (as I think you're saying) your machine is the SVN server, but the actual files are stored on a separate fileserver accessed via a network share, then this should be ok because you won't have the contention for simultaneous access. That will be handled by the server process.

If though you have it set up so that each user maps the network drive and runs their own server, with the same shared repository then this is likely to be dangerous.

So, you should be ok but moving it to the desktop with a daily sync to the server may be safer (and give faster access too).  If you have the repository stored in FSFS format (as is the recommendation) then you can just run `robocopy` hourly or nightly and it'll back up very quickly.

Comment: It's the former - one svn server. Thanks for the answer. Will accept this tomorrow if nobody chimes in with contrary information in the meantime.